# store unique events with Firebase and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I am building an app for iOS with swift and Cloud Firestore (firebase) that allows the user to create home inspection reports.  On the first page, the initial data is entered into text fields: name, address, photo of home etc.  Once that data is entered and the "create new report" button is pressed. How do I make sure each report created is a totally unique event (or unique document?) that can be recalled later?  So the next time one creates a new report, their data is separate and contained in its own container.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you [call `addDocument` to add a new document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document), Firestore generates a random, unique ID for that new document. So that sounds perfect for your use-case: whenever the user clicks the <kbd>create new report</kbd> button, you add a document by calling `addDocument` and then use that document's ID as the identifier for that report.

Comment: To clarify: Would I have to put all data for that inspection into a single document?  OR, are the other documents in that same collection connected in some way to this specific inspection document's uniqueID (e.g. customer, agent, inspector, property)?  I am used to working with foreign and primary keys in SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the follow up question here. If you're new to NoSQL databases, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).